# Writing Objective C objects into firebase

Tags: objective-c, firebase

I've been using firebase successfully to read and write data for an iOS app. Now I'm starting to need to store and retrieve more complex objects. I want to make sure I'm proceeding in the correct manner.

I've got a class such as,

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *id;

@end
```

When I write this class into firebase,

```
MyClass *myClass1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
myClass1.name = @"Bakery";
myClass1.id = @"1";

[firebase setValue:myClass1];
```

An exception is thrown,

'Unknown class in payload: MyClass; only NSDictionary and NSArray supported.'

I see in the iOS firebase docs that NSNumber, NSString, NSArray and NSDictionary are listed as the types the setValue: can handle.

Does this mean I can't use setValue:on my classes? Do I need to unwrap my objects into instances of the NSNumber, NSString, NSArray or NSDictionary objects to store data? I was thinking that the iOS firebase implementation would be able to serialize simple objects to save to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

[You have to get your objects into strings, you can write booleans, numbers, and objects](https://www.firebase.com/docs/writing-data.html), where `objects` consist of strings, dates, booleans, and numbers that are persisted in Firebase. These seem to be [strings, dates, data, real and whole numbers (including booleans)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i).

Comment: My object only contain strings. Maybe I'm not following you.

Comment: But, your object is called MyClass and doesn't implement NSCoding. `[firebase setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:myClass1.name, myClass1.id, nil]]` should get you past this problem, but the real solution is to have your class implement NSCoding, as the above answer recommends.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I'll give NSCoding a try when I get a chance. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'd never looked at NSCoding before and tried this and it didn't work. I think perhaps I didn't state my goal clearly. I can unroll my classes into base objects and save them individually into the database. I'm doing that now. I also don't want to store the objects as blobs of serialized text that can only be encode/decoded under IOS. I was expecting that the Firebase interface would be able to take simple objects and JSON serialize them into Firebase tree structure and back without a lot of the detailed coding that I'm doing now.

Comment: @marks Firebase data is entirely JSON. Everything written or read is JSON. So your expectation has been fulfilled?

Comment: Kato, No my expectations have not been fulfilled. I can write my Objective C objects into Firebase if I break them down into strings, arrays or dictionaries, etc. I can restore these object with some ugly code that builds them from the strings, arrays and dictionaries. I was hoping for some thing more elegant. For example, I have another app where I serialize the objects into JSON and then send the JSON over to a server where it is stored.

Comment: Look into Objective C JSON class libraries such as [sbjson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/‎)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Firebase, but what about `NSData`? It seems like it should be able to accept that.

Almost any object can easily be turned into `NSData` using:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myClass1];

// and the reverse:
myClass1 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Note you will have to implement `<NSCoding>` in your class, which is also pretty straightforward (many good tutorials available, have a quick search).

If it can't handle NSData either, I'd file a feature request with them, then convert the NSData object into an NSString:

```
NSString *dataString = [data base64Encoding]; // this is deprecated in iOS 7 / OS X 10.9. But not available in earlier versions.

NSString *dataString = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]; // new API
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a 3rd party library like Mantle to aid you in serializing/deserializing your objects to/from JSON:

https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle.

That should help with some of the boilerplate you're writing.